# Merge datasets with left_join()

Tags: r, left-join

im working on merging datasets with function `left_join()`.

The datasets im using are the above:

```
> new_GemData<-lapply(GemData, head)
> dput(head(new_GemData))
list(cntry = c(".", "ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB"), all_tea = c(6.2942258871149, 
NA, NA, 26.1555808326023, NA, NA), all_nes_entre = c(1.88915438310442, 
NA, NA, 7.6296866239702, NA, NA), all_opp_entre = c(4.32969440907848, 
NA, NA, 17.1323566956254, NA, NA), all_tea_male_entre = c(8.96311504196867, 
NA, NA, 26.9322388085985, NA, NA), all_tea_female_entre = c(3.53006299869866, 
NA, NA, 25.5152945703973, NA, NA))
> new_Hofstede<-lapply(Hofstede, head)
> dput(head(new_Hofstede))
list(ctr = c("ALB", "ALG", "AND", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM"), country = c("Albania", 
"Algeria", "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia"
), `Power Distance` = c(".", ".", ".", "80", "49", "."), Individualism = c(".", 
".", ".", "38", "46", "."), Masculinity = c(".", ".", ".", "53", 
"56", "."), `Uncertainty Avoidance` = c(".", ".", ".", "68", 
"86", "."))
> new_GpsData<-lapply(GpsData, head)
> dput(head(new_GpsData))
list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Bangladesh"), isocode = c("AFG", "DZA", "ARG", "AUS", 
"AUT", "BGD"), patience = c(-0.201360121369362, 0.0598152466118336, 
-0.229307979345322, 0.65700376033783, 0.608285009860992, 0.0811367109417915
), risktaking = c(0.120764262974262, 0.391530483961105, 0.0415031686425209, 
0.137136548757553, -0.0618291534483433, -0.198067754507065), 
    posrecip = c(0.2896409034729, -0.598255336284637, 0.159679308533669, 
    0.069660022854805, 0.161046594381332, 0.154367566108704), 
    negrecip = c(0.254712462425232, 0.254900813102722, -0.140457272529602, 
    0.0221897512674332, -0.0554154515266418, 0.113288171589375
    ))
```

The common column i need is the Country Names, i know that ISO3 is the most appropriate method to merge them.

Here im trying to merge them:

```
new_Hofstede$code=countrycode(new_Hofstede$`country`, origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')

merged_data2 <- new_Hofstede %>% 
  rename(iso3 = 'code') %>% 
  left_join(new_GemData, by = c('iso3' = 'cntry') )

all_data2 <- left_join(merged_data2, new_GpsData, by=c("iso3"="isocode"))
```

**EDIT:** *I dont know if the merge i have done is correct and  i would like your suggestions , proposals on how to merge these datasets, GEM, Hofstede and GPS.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in `left_join()` what the field name is in each table, no need to rename ahead of time. Does this give what you want? I drop `country` from `new_GpsData` because it already is there from another table.

```r
library(dplyr)

new_Hofstede %>% 
  left_join(new_GemData, by = c(ctr = "cntry")) %>% 
  left_join(select(new_GpsData, -country), by = c(ctr = "isocode"))
```

Comment: Sir so we have achieved to merge these 3 datasets correctly ? I understand your suggestion now.